# How to work with memory addresses in C? Are they hexadexcimals or unsigned ints?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, memory, unsigned-integer

I am learning C and recently had my class on pointers and memory addresses.
The teacher told us that memory locations are basically unsigned numbers, so we can display them using the following code:

```
int a;
printf("%u", &a);
```

or

```
int a, *p=&a;
printf("%u", p);
```

Indeed, this works, but I also read in some forums that one should use %p or %x for printing addresses. So, they must be hex numbers... Are the integers I am seeing above actually hexadecimal numbers converted to decimal? And what are addresses actually in their basic form - hex or integer or simply binary nos.

Please help me on this.

Comment: Hexadecimal and Decimal are just arbitrary representations of numbers. You can't say a number is *explicitly* hex or dec, it's both.

Comment: Your question is like asking "Is a quarter 25 cents, or 1/4 of a dollar?". Hex and decimal are just two ways of looking at the same value.

Comment: I understand this now. I should not see them as two different numbers but one number represented in two ways. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can't say it's an unsigned int, either. A pointer is best treated as its own thing that has some similarity to an unsigned int.

Comment: *On some systems* memory addresses are similar to numbers, however this is not generally true and also you should try to not think of them as numbers, to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Addresses in their basic form are simply values. Hex, or binary, or octal are *representations* of a number. For example, `42`, `0x2a`, `2a16`, `052`, `528`, `1010102` and `1042` are all different *representations* of the same *value.*

In terms of what you should be using as a format string, `%p` is the correct one. There is no guarantee that unsigned integers will have the same number of bits as a pointer so you may well lose information.

In fact, providing and argument to `printf` that doesn't match the corresponding format specifier is actually undefined behaviour.

Using `%u` or `%x` variants may well work on most systems where pointers and unsigned integers are of a compatible size but truly portable code wouldn't rely on that. For example, an implementation is free to have a 16-bit unsigned integer (to satisfy the minimum range requirements in `ISO C11 Appendix E`) and a 1024-bit pointer type (I gotta get me one of *those* machines).

Answer (score 2):

Learning C, one of the hurdles everyone has to get over is making friends with pointers. In C, unlike other languages, you are coding at a very low-level of the machine and that just about everything you do in C is a memory operation. The key to learning C is knowing "What is at that memory address?", "How big of a block of memory do I have?" and "How do I work with it correctly?". Unfortunately, many times people make that process much harder than it needs to be.

One thing that really helps, and that is fundamental to understanding a bulk of low-level programming, is simply that all variables are nothing more than a **label**, or better yet, an **alias for a memory address**.

The only thing that differentiates a normal variable and a pointer variable is that instead of being an **alias** to where some **direct** or **immediate** value is stored in memory (like `5` or `21`), a pointer is an **alias** to a memory location where the **address of something else is stored**. Simply put, a pointer stores a memory address as its value.

Think of the basics this way:

```
int x = 5;
```

What is `x`? It's a **label for a memory address**. What memory address does `x` label (alias)? `&x`. What's stored at that address? `5`. Good so far?

Well, what are pointers?

```
int *y;         /* what's so special about the '*' in the declaration?
                   Nothing, just basic syntax for pointer declaration. */

y = &x;         /* which stores the address of x as the value of y.
                   And what is x? -- a label to a memory location */
```

What is `y`? It's a **label for a memory address**. What memory address does `y` label (alias)? `&y`. What's stored at that address? `&x` (the address of `x`). Still good?

Then let's look at a short example to hopefully help cement the basics, so you can move on to truly using pointers as intended, to access and manipulate blocks of memory such as arrays, linked-lists, stacks, etc...:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void prn_values (int val, int *ptr);

int main (void) {

    int x = 5;          /* declare variable & pointer   */
    int *y = &x;        /* y now holds the address of x */
    prn_values (x, y);

    int z = 7;
    y = &z;             /* y now holds the address of z */
    prn_values (z, y);

    z = x;              /* y still holds the value of z,  */
    prn_values (z, y);  /* but the value of z has changed */

    *y = 9;             /* y still holds z, but we have changed z by     */
                        /* changing the value at the address stored in y */
    printf ("\n  z : %-14d (value)\n &z : %-14p (address)\n", z, &z);

    /* actually using a pointer to an array */
    char array[] = "pointer arithmetic.";
    char *p = array;    /* p points to the start address of array */

    printf ("\n array    : %p (address)\n array [0]: %p (address)\n\n",
            array, &array[0]);

    while (*p) {
        printf ("     %c    : %p\n", *p, p);
        p++;
    }

    return 0;
}

void prn_values (int val, int *ptr)
{
    printf ("\n  x : %-14d (value)\n &x : %-14p (address)\n", val, &val);

    printf ("  y : %-14p (value)\n &y : %-14p (address)\n *y : %-14d "
            "(dereference)\n", ptr, &ptr, *ptr);
}
```

**Compile**

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -o pointers pointers.c
```

**Output**

Below, the integer pointer `y` is assigned the value of `x`, then `z` and the values, addresses and value at the address of the pointer are output. **Note** how the value of the pointer is the address of the variable it points to. While `y` points to `z`, the value of `z` is changed. Since `y` holds (points to) the memory address aliased by `z`, `*y` reflects the change as well. Then note how the change works both ways. If the value at the address held by `y` is changed by assignment to `*y`, the change is reflected in `z` as well.

That is all rudimentary pointer basics, that does very little to show the true power and use of pointers. It is **pointer arithmetic** and the ability to pass a pointer as a function argument where the use and value of pointers is seen. Note how the final while loop, uses the pointer `p` to the character array to access each and every address (holding a character) in the array by nothing more than incrementing `p` by 1 (`p++;`) during each iteration.

```
$ ./pointers

  x : 5              (value)
 &x : 0x7ffff2c72590 (address)
  y : 0x7ffff2c72590 (value)
 &y : 0x7ffff2c725b0 (address)
 *y : 5              (dereference)

  z : 7              (value)
 &z : 0x7ffff2c725a0 (address)
  y : 0x7ffff2c725a0 (value)
 &y : 0x7ffff2c725b0 (address)
 *y : 7              (dereference)

  z : 5              (value)
 &z : 0x7ffff2c725a0 (address)
  y : 0x7ffff2c725a0 (value)
 &y : 0x7ffff2c725b0 (address)
 *y : 5              (dereference)

  z : 9              (value)
  z : 0x7ffff2c725a0 (address)

 array    : 0x7ffff2c725c0 (address)
 array [0]: 0x7ffff2c725c0 (address)

     p    : 0x7ffff2c725c0
     o    : 0x7ffff2c725c1
     i    : 0x7ffff2c725c2
     n    : 0x7ffff2c725c3
     t    : 0x7ffff2c725c4
     e    : 0x7ffff2c725c5
     r    : 0x7ffff2c725c6
          : 0x7ffff2c725c7
     a    : 0x7ffff2c725c8
     r    : 0x7ffff2c725c9
     i    : 0x7ffff2c725ca
     t    : 0x7ffff2c725cb
     h    : 0x7ffff2c725cc
     m    : 0x7ffff2c725cd
     e    : 0x7ffff2c725ce
     t    : 0x7ffff2c725cf
     i    : 0x7ffff2c725d0
     c    : 0x7ffff2c725d1
     .    : 0x7ffff2c725d2
```

Pointer arithmetic works for all array types (char, int, struct foo, whatever). By declaring a pointer of `type X`, the compiler knows the size of data type `X`. Through pointer arithmetic, access to and iteration of complex data-types is no different. Pointers to functions and pointers to pointers work the same way. As you gain more experience, you will come to rely on pointers as a large part of your C toolbox, so it is well worth the time spent to understand the basics thoroughly. Passing pointers as function arguments is another entire facet of how pointers are used in C. Since this answer grew much longer than originally intended, we will leave that for another day. Let me know if you have any questions. Good luck with C.

Comment: That was a handy guide to pointer introduction! Thanks a lot. This helped me understand many new concepts.

Comment: Glad I could help. The true key to understanding the power of C is the realize, unlike other languages, you are coding at a very low-level of the machine and that just about everything you do in C is a memory operation. That is why the key to really being able to code fluently in C is knowing "What is at that memory address?", "How big of a block of memory do I have?" and "How do I work with it?".  The key to working with memory is a pointer. Why? -- It's the only type of variable that holds a memory address as its value.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s the standard way of doing it in C:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  int x = 0;

  printf( "The value of &x is %" PRIxPTR " in hex and %" PRIuPTR
            " in decimal, and %%p displays %p.\n",
          (uintptr_t)&x,
          (uintptr_t)&x,
          (void*)&x);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

A `uintptr_t` is an integer that’s able to store a pointer to an object safely.

And the C++ solution:

```
#include <climits>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::resetiosflags;
using std::setfill;
using std::setiosflags;
using std::setw;
using std::streamsize;

int main(void) {
  int x = 0;

  static const streamsize hex_width = static_cast<streamsize>(sizeof(int*)*CHAR_BIT/4);
  static const streamsize dec_width = 0;    // Don't pad.

  cout << "The value of &x is " << resetiosflags(cout.basefield) << setw(hex_width) << setfill('0')
       << setiosflags(cout.hex) << reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&x) << " in hex, "
       << resetiosflags(cout.basefield) << setw(dec_width)
       << setiosflags(cout.dec) << reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&x) << " in decimal, and "
       << resetiosflags(cout.basefield) << static_cast<void*>(&x) << " as a pointer." << endl;

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

Answer (score 0):

In a computer, everything is a number if you look closely enough :)

A pointer is indeed a number. The only problem is, the size of that number depends on the hardware architecture and memory model.

For instance, some processors use 64 bit addresses, while microcontrollers might use only 16 bits.
Even on a 64 bits processor, a given process may be limited to 32 bits addresses (typically the WIN32 architecture that can run on a 64 bits processor).

If you try to print a pointer using %u, you have no guarantee the size of an integer will be equal to the size of a pointer. Typically on a WIN64 architecture %u would only display the first 32 bits of a pointer.

The %p format, on the other hand, takes the actual pointer size into account and guarantees its value will be displayed properly.

Comment: I get it now... Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The portable way to print the address of an object is

```
int a, *p=&a;
printf("%p", (void *) p);
```

The `"%p"` specifier matches a `void*`.  C does not provide a `printf()` specifier for `int *`, but all objects pointers can convert to a `void*`.

Many architectures use a linear address starting at 0 to some large value which may exceed `INT_MAX`.   Yet C provides for many address schemes.  The output of the above could be any of the below and not necessarily only made up of numeric characters:

```
123456789
0x0001C800
1000:0008
int:0000
```

Comment: Why (void*) p? Why not simply printf("%d", p);

Comment: @AnirudhKhanna Because `%p` only works with `void *`

Comment: @Anirudh Khanna `printf()` specifier `"%d"`matches an `int`.  `"%d"` may not provide the proper output with a pointer.  It is _undefined behavior_.  Your code may see an expected result on one platform, a crash on another.

Answer (score -2):

The both is right.
Try this code:

```
int a = 10;
printf("%p\n%u", &a, &a);
```

will print the pointer address in hex ( %p ) and in uint ( %u ).
If you convert hex to uint, use calc of windows in developer mode, 
you will have the same value.

Read this: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Pointers_and_arrays

Drink coffe and keep coding! =)

Comment: This causes undefined behaviour by using the wrong format specifier (twice).  You need to cast the value to the right type.

Comment: I'm not a c user, but I thought "&a" identifies a (void*) pointer to a? so %p would be ok.  Perhaps this is a difference between c and c++?

Comment: Code , compile and run. The both works, the first show hex value and the second show unsigned value. After, convert hex in unsigned ( 10 base ) and you get the same value. All addresses in C/C++ are void pointer in memory, the type is used for the value and for step size when walking in memory.